# Oracle - automatically create a rollback script

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

is there any way to automatically generate a rollback script for a SQL ?

For example :

```
  SQL script      : Delete from table_A where name = 'John Doe'

  rollback script : Insert into table_A values (..... )
```

Comment: Something about this seems programmatically wrong.

Comment: @alexherm - if you are aware of production deployments, "rollback scripts" or "rollback plans" are almost mandatory. They are used to reverse the changes. Not sure what you meant "programmatically wrong"

Comment: For what purpose?  You could use flashback to undo the transaction after it was committed (though it may depend on how your UNDO is configured) and as part of that you could get the backout script (though you'd generally run the `dbms_flashback.backout_transaction` command rather than running the backout script). https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/flashback-and-logminer-enhancements-11gr1#flashback_transaction   An alternative would be to create a restore point and do a database flashback if you had to revert.

Comment: @JustinCave - the reason I want to do this is to allow a developer logically reverse changes made to a database during production rollout - without having to worry about flashback privileges or undo configuration. Also - flashing back a production database will affect all users connected to database. A logical rollback will be limited to only few tables or schemas

Comment: Hence asking what the business problem is-- trying to do a backout as part of a production deploy is different from, say, wanting to reverse any changes that get made as part of running a test suite so that the database is back to a known good state.  Doing a transaction flashback would be a plausible solution for a production deploy though it may reqiure a bit of work to integrate with your deploy process (i.e. if scripts have to be uploaded to change control before the deploy

Comment: It's a good question. It would be great to have a tool to generate the backout script automatically. Or maybe have a tool that compares two schemas or sets of objects and generates the change script and backout script. There are some CICD tools but they don't seem to really do everything.

Comment: oradbanj I wondered whether you can consider third-party libraries that do this (liquibase for example has this feature), or whether you are only looking for something purely internal to the database server?

Comment: @oradbanj How are you going to reverse  update script without storing values somewhere? `UPDATE t SET col  = 1 WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 1000000;` I doubt such tool exists to make such cases automatically. You should try backup/snapshoting/or wrapping everything in transaction and rollback if something fails.

Answer (score 0):

TOAD has this built-in feature wherein you can generate INSERT scripts.

1. Write the SELECT query in TOAD and execute it

   `SELECT * from table_A where name = 'John Doe'`
2. In the data that shows up in data grid window, right-click and choose Export Dataset option.
3. In the Export Dataset window, choose Insert Statements option from the Export Format drop-down.
4. Specify the file name in the File field to get the output in a file, or you can choose output to the Clipboard too.
5. Click on the OK button to generate the Insert statements script.

   HTH!